# Showing asterisk (*) symbol to the right of label text using CSS

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I would like to display asterisk mark on the label text to the right position using CSS but could not succeed in vaadin 8.6.2

```
.v-label-wrap {
content: " *";
color: red;
position: absolute;
white-space: normal !important;
word-break: normal !important;
word-wrap: normal !important;
}

Label lblAttr = new Label("Name");
lblAttr.addStyleName("wrap");
```

An asterisk * with red color need to be displayed. Please advice how to solve this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `::after` like this :

```css
.v-label-wrap::after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}
```

More info about after : [MDN ::after/:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

> It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default.